# Change boilerplate for new Gradle module with IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, module, boilerplate

What's the best way to streamline the creation of new modules in a Gradle project with IntelliJ?

Every time I create a new Gradle module I have a small todo list before I write any code. Whenever I create a new library module, I do the following after IntelliJ does its normal boilerplate setup.

1. Apply the *java-library* plugin (and often *checkerframework*).
2. Add lombok preprocessors.
3. Add dependency `compileOnly 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}'`.
4. Bump JUnit version.
5. Add testing dependencies.

   - `testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:${junitVersion}'`
   - `testRuntimeOnly 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}'`
6. Copy-paste standard config to `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml`.
7. Create empty packages at `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` with the same name as the [group](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:group) name.

This only takes a few minutes each time, but I have gotten annoyed enough to spend time writing this question in search of better way.

I don't know the best way to begin to approach this. I don't even know if I should be looking for a solution through Gradle or IntelliJ. I have found info about structuring projects, creating templates, custom tasks, custom plugins, etc. I feel this must be a common enough task that there is an established best practice.

I'm not asking for much technical detail about how to implement the solution. I can probably figure it out once I know what kind of solution to use.

Comment: The approach to add a new module is likely to be different b/w each team, project and person.  Since this is likely project specific, you can write it as a gradle task; long with a template new-module-folder - then you can call it to add new modules on demand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it in the following way:

- `File | New | Project | New Project | Gradle`
- Add the needed configuration
- `File | New Project Setup | Save Project as Template`
- Create a new project using a custom template.
- Open your main project and add a new project as module under `File | Project Structure | Modules | + | Import Module`

Repeat the last two steps when adding a new module with a custom setup.